# Editing LaTeX files

Tags: editors, publishing

I hope that this is correct forum. What is the best way to edit a LaTeX file that I have not generated myself?

I am often sent LaTeX files converted to Word for copyediting, however the conversion process causes havoc with the document formatting, symbols and tables.

In order to save the authors time (and distress!) I'd like to be able to edit their files directly as LaTeX - without converting.

Can I do this using the LyX software, or is there a better option?

Comment: You can choose your own poison from this list https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  you can use any text editor to edit a latex file -- latex files are "uncorrupted" text files, in a common standard encoding, which may be anything from ascii to utf-8.  i don't use lyx, so i can't speak authoritatively, but i believe it doesn't "recognize" some latex packages; if nothing really unusual is present in the latex file, though, i think it shouldn't be a problem, and at least worth trying.

Comment: You might want to look at [online LaTeX editors](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/admin/html/onlinetex.shtml).